# Equivalent of mssql_result in sqlsrv (Microsoft SQL Driver for PHP)

Tags: php, sql-server

What is the equivalent function for mssql_result, under Microsoft SQL Driver for PHP (sqlsrv)? Please give example of using that function as well. I couldn't find any details on this online, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest equivalent seems to be sqlsrv_get_field(). See here for the documentation and code samples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296207(v=SQL.90).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296152(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I agree with sqlsrv_get_field being the right answer (but I can't vote for it because I don't have enough reputation points yet). For a complete comparison of mssql and sqlsrv functions, see this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/03/10/mssql-vs-sqlsrv-what-s-the-difference-part-2.aspx.